# Bootstrap spacing issue

Tags: html, web, frontend, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to make an application form from scratch using Bootstrap. Everything is going on fine except this one issue. The issue here is that the element with ID of `officeaddress` is not visible on the HTML page when loaded up. I've tried using the `my` class of Bootstrap and also tried adding line breaks in between. Yet no result. Herewith attaching the code for your reference.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Parent's details</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container"> <br>

        <h1 class="text-center">Your Parent's details</h1>

        <form>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6 ">
                    <label for="fathername">Father's name: </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fathername">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="mothername">Mother's name: </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mothername">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="fatherno">Father's no. : </label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="fatherno">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="motherno">Mother's no. : </label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="motherno">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="fathermail">Father's mail ID : </label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="fathermail">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="mothermail">Mother's mail ID : </label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="mothermail">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="annualincome">Annual Income:</label>
                    <select id="annualincome" class="form-control">
                        <option selected>Select:</option>
                        <option value="&lt;50000">&lt;50,000</option>
                        <option value="&gt;50000 and &lt;200000"> &gt;50,000 and &lt;2,00,000</option>
                        <option value="&gt;200000 and &lt;500000"> &gt;2,00,000 and &lt;5,00,000</option>
                        <option value="&gt;500000 and &lt;800000"> &gt;5,00,000 and &lt;8,00,000</option>
                        <option value="&gt;800000 and &lt;1000000"> &gt;8,00,000 and &lt;10,00,000</option>
                        <option value="&gt;1000000 and &lt;1200000"> &gt;10,00,000 and &lt;12,00,000</option>
                        <option value="&gt;1200000"> &gt;1200000</option>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="officeaddress">Office Address line 1</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pfficeaddress">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="officeaddress2">Office Address line 2</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="officeaddress2">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="officeno">Office no. : </label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="officeno">
            </div>
        </form>

        <a href="educational.html">Proceed to enter educational details</a>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Off topic: You're missing a closing `div` tag at the bottom, and line break elements shouldn't be used for layout spacing.

Comment: Typo: `pfficeaddress`

Comment: You're also missing a closing `select` tag. I suggest a better editor setup or a run through an HTML validator.

Comment: Yes. I just realized that I missed a ```select``` tag. I did not notice it before posting the question. Shall try not to repeat the same again. Thank you for the quick response :)

Comment: Feel free to delete your question to recover reputation points.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a closing tag for "select" regarding the "annualincome" class.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Parent's details</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container"> <br>

        <h1 class="text-center">Your Parent's details</h1>

        <form>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6 ">
                    <label for="fathername">Father's name: </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fathername">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="mothername">Mother's name: </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mothername">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="fatherno">Father's no. : </label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="fatherno">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="motherno">Mother's no. : </label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="motherno">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="fathermail">Father's mail ID : </label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="fathermail">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="mothermail">Mother's mail ID : </label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="mothermail">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="annualincome">Annual Income:</label>
                    <select id="annualincome" class="form-control">
                        <option selected>Select:</option>
                        <option value="&lt;50000">&lt;50,000</option>
                        <option value="&gt;50000 and &lt;200000"> &gt;50,000 and &lt;2,00,000</option>
                        <option value="&gt;200000 and &lt;500000"> &gt;2,00,000 and &lt;5,00,000</option>
                        <option value="&gt;500000 and &lt;800000"> &gt;5,00,000 and &lt;8,00,000</option>
                        <option value="&gt;800000 and &lt;1000000"> &gt;8,00,000 and &lt;10,00,000</option>
                        <option value="&gt;1000000 and &lt;1200000"> &gt;10,00,000 and &lt;12,00,000</option>
                        <option value="&gt;1200000"> &gt;1200000</option>
                        </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="officeaddress">Office Address line 1</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pfficeaddress">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="officeaddress2">Office Address line 2</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="officeaddress2">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="officeno">Office no. : </label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="officeno">
            </div>
        </form>

        <a href="educational.html">Proceed to enter educational details</a>
</body>

</html>
```